# mvc sorting dont change

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, sorting, razor

I have an MVC project. And I am using jQuery ajax post for sorting my products. Controllers below.

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Category() //this is first level. And its working....
    {
            var result = Url.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["categoryName"].ToString();
            const string sorttype = "A/Z";
            var liste = _productRepository.GetProductByCategoryName(result);
            List<Product> deger;
            switch (sorttype)
            {
                case "A/Z":
                    deger = liste.OrderBy(s => s.ProductName).ToList();
                    break;
            }
            var modelim = new CategoryViewModel
                {
                    Catname = result,
                    Products = deger
                };
                return View(modelim);

    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Category(string sortingName, string catName)//get to jquery post.
    {
        string sorttype = sortingName;
        var liste = _productRepository.GetProductByCategoryName(catName);
        List<Product> deger = null;
        switch (sorttype)
        {
            case "A/Z":
                deger = liste.OrderBy(s => s.ProductName).ToList();
                break;
            case "Z/A":
                deger = liste.OrderByDescending(s => s.ProductName).ToList();
                break;
            case "Fiyat Artan":
                deger = liste.OrderBy(s => s.ProductPrice).ToList();
                break;
            case "Fiyat Azalan":
                deger = liste.OrderByDescending(s => s.ProductPrice).ToList();
                break;

        }
        var modelim = new CategoryViewModel
        {
            Catname = catName,
            Products = deger //this is new ordered list!!!!
        };
        return View(modelim);

    }
```

I have changed my product list ordered. And I sent new model my razor page. But nothing has changed. ?????? What is wrong? Thanks a lot.

And my jQuery file below,

```
$('#sortList').on({
change:function() {
    var result = $('#sortList option:selected').text();
    var catname = $('#catName').text();
    var message = { 'sortingName': result, 'catName': catname };
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Category/Category',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(message),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error) {

            } if (data.success) {

            }
        }


    });

}
```

});

Comment: Not sure it will help in this case, but have you tried adding `ModelState.Clear()` to the top of your postback Category function? Your model might be getting cached.

Comment: Have you checked that sortingName is changing when doing the post?  Also can you put your jquery code?

Comment: MassivePenguin I tryed. But dont change. And Moe yes I show all value on my controller. I Put my jquery code above.

Comment: And I am showing new ordered model on My Razor page. But When page load I cant see changing.

Comment: Try appending the arguments to the AJAX URL (eg `url: '/Category/Category?sortingName=' + result + '&catName=' + catname`... I've had trouble when posting `data` via jQuery to an MVC controller. Plus... what are you actually doing when the `data.success` is returned? Replacing the whole HTML of the page? If that's the case, why not just use a regular postback?

Comment: Dear MassivePenguin I think not important success or error at thip point. first off all Just I want to jquery send new data on my controller. Just it. And My controller return values on my razor page. I show new value and new ordered list with breakpoint. But I cant show on my razor page. Problem this.

Comment: And I am sorry for my english.:)

Comment: and change jquery get. but not working...... What is wrong? I cant undestand.

Comment: So what *is* happening when you post the data? Is your controller being hit?